# Vue Vuetify.Wrong index is passed to v-dialog when using v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-for

So using v-for and v-dialog, my template looking like this:

```
  <v-list >
   <v-list-item v-for="(pool,indexp) in items[0].pools" :key="pool.name">
     <v-dialog :retain-focus="false" v-model="dialog" scrollable max-width="300px">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
       <v-btn color="primary" dark v-on="on">{{pool.name}}</v-btn>
        </template>
                <v-card><v-card-title>{{pool.name}}</v-card-title></v-card>
     </v-dialog>
    </v-list-item>
  </v-list>
```

So say the object I'm looping through has 2 elements, this generates 2 buttons that will activate the v-dialog. My problem is that when I click the first "pool" button, the name of the second pool is shown in the dialog. WHy?

I have this in codepen:

https://codepen.io/averied/pen/QWjXxop?editable=true&editors=101%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fvuetifyjs.com%2Fen%2Fcomponents%2Fdialogs%2F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re using the same boolean variable, `dialog`, for everything in the v-for as it appears to me, then activating one will activate them all. Later ones will be rendered over top of earlier ones. So in a two item list you’ll always see the second item.

You probably don’t need the v-model on the v-dialog at all; I’m fairly certain the v-dialogs can maintain their internal state just fine. Unless you’re programmatically triggering the dialogs through something other than your button in the activator slot, or if you need to display or save the state for some reason. If so, you’ll need to maintain a list of booleans, one for each pool. Could potentially be an attribute on the pool object.

Comment: How do I close the v-dialog without the v-model??

Comment: Clicking outside the dialog, same as before. If your actual code is more complex than the example, and you need to trigger the v-dialog to close by some other means, you can post another codepen and I might be able to make a better suggestion

Comment: I need the dialog to be "persistent" (modal), so that the user clicks a save button. This is a new codepen, thanks for helping: https://codepen.io/averied/pen/XWmLBMy?editable=true&editors=101%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fvuetifyjs.com%2Fen%2Fcomponents%2Fdialogs%2F

Comment: Ok, so you are programmatically triggering dialogs through the method you call when you click the close button. You do need the v-model, but you `dialog` should be an array, and you need to pass the index to your close method so it can close the right dialog. I had to use `this.$set` to get the reactivity to pick up the change for some reason, might be related to the slightly odd environment of CodePen. Anyway, this will do what you need: https://codepen.io/djsmedes/pen/PoPrrMJ?editors=1010

Comment: As a general rule of good application design, I'd recommend creating a component whenever you start having to deal with maintaining parallel arrays and passing around indices.